# OptionsMenu in nested fragments with Nav component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using [Navigation Architecture Component](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/)
 and nested fragments (only 1 activity in my app and shared ToolBar). In fragment A I do:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.scan_menu, menu)
}
```

Then I show a new fragment B using something like this:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_a_b)
```

The navigation part of it works fine, but the menu created in fragment A sticks around when fragment b is shown (actually, it is never cleared). Isn't this supported in the nav arch components? How am I supposed to attack this? I do not wan't to perform hacks by clearing the menu manually in literally all other fragment due to one of them adding a menu.

Thanks!

Comment: Add menu.clear(); before inflating on OnCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: That's a hack imho? I do not wanna perform hacks by clearing the menu manually in literally all other fragment due to one of them adding a menu.

Comment: Would it be suitable to do the menu.clear() on the onDestroyOptionsMenu() call on the single fragment instead?

Comment: onDestroyOptionsMenu() is never called in the fragment, I guess that's a part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there doesn't seem to be any solution, I ended up with keeping a reference to the MenuItem, and hide/show:

```
private var menuItem: MenuItem? = null

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.scan_menu, menu)
    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.scan_menu_manual)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    menuItem?.isVisible = true
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    menuItem?.isVisible = false
}
```

That seems to work for now.